# Export data with phpmyadmin, ordered on row-level

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, export-to-csv

I'm working with a huge database with more than 800 tables and over 50,000 rows in total. All these tables have different structures, with the exception of a timestamp field which is present in all tables.

My challenge: export all data but be able to use the timestamp field in a meaningful way.

For statistical purposes I want to create an overview of all the entries into this database in which I can work with the timestamp field. The problem with a "normal" export is that the data is ordered by table, then ID. This means that all the timestamp fields are in a different columns (using excel here), and I can't effectively use it to sort the entries based on this field.

*TL;DR version*: Is it possible to export all data from a database managed with PHPMyAdmin ordered by a field that is present in all tables, while all the other fields are table-specific?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you want to do is first get the information in the format you would like and then export it. First though, you need to figure out exactly what you are trying to accomplish. You might rather create the SQL to do the statistical (counting, summing, averaging, etc.) work and then just use Excel for the final product. Views and alternate indexes provide logical ways of looking at the data.

As I understand what you are attempting, you need to recreate your database with the timestamp field as the major key for each table. Without physically rewriting the database I don't think you can use phpmyadmin's export to export in the format you want.

Comment: That's too bad; the database is really, *really* ginormeous, close to 15,000 records distributed over about 1,000 tables...